# Removing JS once loaded and run one time from Firefox via Selenium/Selenium Wire/Python, feasible?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, seleniumwire

I don't really know the association of JS's connection to the Dom tree, so is this feasible?

Find a list of all JS Functions loaded.
Clobber them somehow, but let them run at least once.

Using Python/Selenium Wire.

This is on a per tab basis, I would have used the JS Disable Addon but it's been discontinued and I can't find another addone with a hotkey to disable the JS.

Other options are to use Devlopers Console F12, then the Debugger (Ctrl-Shift-Z) and Pause (F8) to the Pause the JS.

The only issue is trying it manually the Ctrl-Shift-Z sequence seems flaky, anyone else had this experience or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can remove the scripts from the DOM, but the functions will still be there. You can intercept script requests and abort with CDP but the results will be unpredictable.